# How to make unique date for every element from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making React app and I have such problem:

For instance, I have an array `container` and it looks like this:

```
const container = [
 {item: '1'},
 {item: '2'},
 {item: '3'},
 {item: '4'}
]
```

Then I want to make in html 4 columns and each of them has one value fron this array.. So i'm using this:

```
<div>
 {container.map(t =>
  <div className='box'>{t.item}</div>
 )}
</div>
```

So it'll make 4 `div` with different values: `1/2/3/4`

---

And now my question is here: how to make own date (starting from toda to ...) for every `box`?

1. First item = Monday, 8 June
2. Second item = Tuesday, 9 June

**etc.**

I did something like this, but it shows only current day, bu **I NEED** to show the next days starting from today: 8,9,10,11 etc (the last date doesn't matter it can be 25 June)

```
let x = new Date();

let fullDate = x.toLocaleString('en-gb', { day:'numeric' , weekday: 'long', month: 'long' });
```

P.S. When I'm using `for` It shows all dates in every column.

---

You can see example on the picture:
[image]

EVERY block has current day.. But I need [you can see above]

---

console.log:

[image]

Comment: Please check out [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). it maybe help you

Comment: How this dates should be linked to `item`? Should it be some random dates or consecutive dates starting from today or some other day?

Comment: @DmitryBiletskyy Yes,starting from today.. Sorry, I forgot to add this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: "It shows all dates in every column" There is nothing in your code that would show any date. Please [edit] your question to include the code that is presenting the dates.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added code which I done before, but It shows only current day...

Comment: add 1 day to current date to get your next date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding the date property in each `container` objects.

you do not mention it in your question but by the example I understand you require that the dates be increased from day to day. For this you can add N days to the current date, take a look at the following example, the addDays function adds the number of days you spend per argument to today

```js
const container = [
  {
    item: 1,
    date: new Date(),
  },
  {
    item: 2,
    date: addDays(1),
  },
  {
    item: 3,
    date: addDays(2),
  },
  {
    item: 4,
    date: addDays(3),
  },
];

function addDays(day) {
  const date = new Date();

  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);

  return date;
}

console.log(container);
```

Update 0

```js
// container state after fetching data
const container = [
  {
    item: 1,
  },
  {
    item: 2,
  },
  {
    item: 3,
  },
  {
    item: 4,
  },
];

// container state after transform
const list = container.map((entry) => ({
  ...entry,
  date: addDays(entry.item),
}));

function addDays(day) {
  const date = new Date();

  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);

  return date;
}

console.log(list);
```

Update 1

In order to format dates you can try something like this

```
function format(date) {
  const month = date.getMonth()
  const day = date.getDate()

  return `${month}-${day}`;
}
```

And call format method in this way

```
function addDays(day) {
  const date = new Date();

  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);

  return format(date);
}
```

You can read about date formatting in this super popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Then in react container list it becomes simple

```
<div>
  {container.map((t) => (
    <div className="box">
      <span>{t.item}</span>
      <span>{t.date}</span>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! But In my case , at the beginning I have empty array, then make ajax request and put data from response to this array.. so how to put this func there in my case?

Comment: in this case I would suggest doing it as follows, get the data the same as now, once the data is in the array transform it using map, please check the update to the answer

Comment: Do you mean for example to display only `03-12` in this case `03` could be month and `12` could be date

Comment: I updated the answer in order to show ho to format date, please take a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date to understand about date formatting in javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can generate random Dates with this function

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
//result
const myRandomDate = randomDate(new Date(2020, 6, 8), new Date())
console.log(myRandomeDate)
```

adding dates to the arr of objects

```
const newContainer =[] 
container.forEach(c=>{
  newContainer.push( { item:c.item , date:randomDate(new Date(2020, 6, 8), new Date()) })
})
```

Comment: In console I have random dates, from April, March etc.. I need days starting from today and the next day: 8,9,10,11,12,13...

Comment: how are u getting dates from April and March when the start date is today's 2020/6/8?

Comment: It was my bad, but when I'm using this code It shows this error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`

Comment: added console.log to my answer, I don't know but dates are not from 8... And you can see it shows a lot of information, but I need only week/day/month